# Building software from github on command line linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, command-line-tool

Apologies if the following isn't very clear and is very item specific, but I'm just very confused with what to do next and can't find any answers on google.

I am trying to install beschulz's [WAV2PNG](https://github.com/beschulz/wav2png/blob/master/README.md) software on a Ubuntu server.

I've followed the directions on the page to get the required software :

```
apt-get install make g++ libsndfile1-dev libpng++-dev libpng12-dev libboost-program-options-dev
```

Which seems to have installed correctly, but next it's saying that I need to build it and I can't work out how to do this.

The docs say :

```
cd build
make all
```

Which i've tried but I just get :

```
-bash: cd: build: No such file or directory
```

This is the first time i've had to "build" anything after downloading it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to have performed a `git clone` on the Github repository.

```
you@vnix$ git clone https://github.com/beschulz/wav2png.git
.... stuff happens ...

you@vnix$ cd wav2png/build

you@vnix$ make all
... lots and lots of stuff happens ...
```

If this is your first time, things are likely to fail in interesting and/or intriguing ways.  You probably want to make sure you are in an environment where you can scroll back and look at error messages and copy/paste them into Google or a new question (`tmux`, `screen`, and Emacs `ansi-term` are all popular alternatives, although a terminal with a big enough scrollback buffer and reasonable keyboard bindings to navigate it would be a good start already).